# How to use Free Functions with Objects

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find out/understand exactly how you access data of an object using free functions.

So my free functions look like this (header wise anyways):

```
#ifndef CDSUPPORTFUN_H
#define CDSUPPORTFUN_H

void DisplayCDS(CDX *pCD1, CDX *pCD2, CDX *pCD3);
void ShowCosts(CDX &CD1, CDX &CD2, CDX &CD3);
void MemoryReturn(CDX *pCD1, CDX *pCD2,CDX *pCD3);
#endif
```

Then I have the implementation for what each does. My question is, exactly what do I input into my Main.cpp to access these functions? What information must I pass in the Main.cpp when I call them?

For example, when I use:

```
DisplayCDS(pCD1, pCD2, pCD3);
```

My data is displayed as intended. However is this still passing with a pointer? And how should it look if I am passing my reference?

--

EDIT: Since ShowCosts is passing by reference would the appropriate syntax to retrieve it be:

```
CD1.ReturnCosts();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear things up, there are two ways to pass by reference. You can pass pointers, which point to an instance of an object. Or you pass the actual object to the function, and have the function create references to those objects. To pass by reference with pointers (the way you have it):

Define your function as:

```
void DisplayCDS(CDX *pCD1);
```

and in your Main, call it as:

```
CDX* pCD1;
*pCD1 = something;
DisplayCDS(pCD1);
```

Alternatively, if you don't like pointers, you can define your function to take references and pass an actual object to it rather than a pointer. To do this:

Define your function as:

```
void DisplayCDS(CDX& CD1);
```

and in your Main, call it as:

```
CDX CD1;
CD1 = something;
DisplayCDS(CD1);
```

These two syntaxes accomplish the same thing. You have passed a reference to your function and not copied the object. Note that there will be a difference in how you use pCD1 or CD1 in your function now. If using pointers, you'll have to use pCD1 as:

```
pCD1->CD1MemberVar = blah;
```

or

```
*pCD1.CD1MemberVar = blah;
```

If you used the second syntax, you'll be able to use the object in your function as normal:

```
CD1.CD1MemberVar = blah;
```

Just to further demonstrate how pointers work, you could also use this method, which is a combination of the previous two, and is unnecessarily confusing.

Define your function as

```
DisplayCDS(CDX& CD1);
```

And in Main:

```
CDX* CD1;
*CD1 = something;
DisplayCDS(*CD1);
```

All of these examples should work...I prefer using the CDX& syntax to avoid the use of *'s all over the place. And ->'s.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, passing a pointer is not technically "passing by reference". It is passing an object (a pointer) that points to your object in memory.

Comment: This is wrong and missleading. Although they accomplish pretty much the same thing, passing by pointer is not passing by reference. Passing a pointer is still pass by value. You still create a copy of the argument.

Comment: Constructing a reference from a pointer also has its uses in a lot of situations, so *unnecessarily confusing* isn't the way that I would describe it. It's used a lot when returning references to elements in a container using `operator[]`. And returning `*this` for method chaining and similar things.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Feel free to edit my response to be more clear. There are a lot of details I left out obviously, but it sounded like the OP was just asking how to pass parameters to a function from a main program without copying it. I was just trying to show OP some options. There are obviously a lot of nuances in implementation, but I'll leave OP to learn those. Just trying to give a place to start.

Comment: @user1777820 A good place to start would be not providing false info. Saying that passing pointers is pass-by-reference is wrong. It's not a good place to start at all.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore The main goal of the OP was to pass objects to a function without copying. There are multiple ways to do this. My terminology may be wrong, but my methodology gives OP several options to accomplish his goal. If you want to correct my terminology, I appreciate it, but there's no need to undermine my efforts by calling it all wrong. The terminology is wrong, but the code provides several options to accomplish what OP wanted. Edit my post and fix the terminology if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

If `pCD1` etc are pointers, then `ShowCosts(*pCD1, *pCD2, *pCD3);` would pass references.

Comment: But the function the OP mentions accepts pointers as arguments, so the arguments are all correctly pointers when he does `DisplayCDS(pCD1, pCD2, pCD3);`.

Comment: No, it would pass the objects the pointers point to by reference.

Comment: The function `ShowCosts` takes references according to the header.

Comment: @john, right. I wasn't disagreeing with you. I was just pointing out that it only answered part of the question. When the OP asked *However is this still passing with a pointer?* in regards to the `DisplayCDS` function, the answer was yes that they are pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, exactly what do I input into my Main.cpp to access these functions? What information must I pass in the Main.cpp when I call them?

First, you must include the header that declares them: `#include "cdssupportfun.h"` (or similar). Second you need to pass the parameters specified in the function signatures: `CDX*` is a pointer to a `CDX`, and `CDX&` means that it expects an object that can be passed by non-`const` reference - so basically a non-temporary, non-`const` `CDX` object.

```
DisplayCDS(pCD1, pCD2, pCD3);
```

has as parameters pointers to `pCD1`. To pass by reference, you can for example call:

```
ShowCosts(*pCD1, *pCD2, *pCD3);
```

which dereferences the pointers, and passes the objects they point to by reference.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if they remained the same since the symbols (astericks and such) changed when you call in in the Main function.

Since ShowCosts is receiving it's information by reference would the correct syntax to recover it be:
   
   `CD1.ReturnCost()` 

(With ReturnCost being a member within class CDX))?

Comment: @Rodekki yes, if `ReturnCost` is a member function in class `CDX`, then `CD1.ReturnCost()` is correct.